# React Native EINVALIDPACKAGENAME

Tags: react-native, npm

Any packages that I try to install, for example, `npm I lodash.isequal` returns the error:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDPACKAGENAME
npm ERR! Invalid package name "buffer 2": name can only contain URL-friendly characters
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks